# How can use tables tag in shartPDF

Tags: asp.net, sharppdf

I am using `shartPDF` to generate pdf. i want to use `table` tag but don't know how to use `table` tag in asp.net.

Anyone have any idea.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, do you mean you don't know how to nest tags like <table><tr><td>cell 1</td><td>cell 2</td></tr></table> ? now you see... :)

Comment: @Davide Piras: I know how to create table tag at server side. but don't know how to use table tag in shartPDF.

Comment: Why is this question tagged with "PDFsharp"?

Comment: hi pankaj, please provide more details in your question. i am not able to understand that you whats to show table in pdf document or you wants to show <table> tags as a string in it.

Comment: This question might get more attention if the incorrect tag "PDFsharp" was removed and the correct tag was added.

Comment: Is this about PDFsharp, sharpPDF, or shartPDF (which doesn't appear to exist)?

Comment: I don't want to lower the tone here, but if someone really has created an app called ShartPDF then they need to be introduced to Urban Dictionary.